# Is there any alternative to use of this in static context in java

Tags: java, static, this

I have a class with method called sThread().
Want to refactor the code of sThread() method of mClass.

```
class SClass {
     private Thread sThread;

     public void sSubThread() {

          initalize_sThread();

          //some code

          if (this.sThread != null) {
              return;
          }
     }
 }
```

so I made changes like (below)
created one more utility class with name SubscritpionThread with static method.

```
class mClass {
    // some code

    public void sThread() {
        SThread.sThreadStart();       
    }
}

class SThread {

    private static Thread sThread;

    private static void initalize_sThread() {
        //  some code
    }

    public static void sThreadStart() {
        // some code
        // changed this to classname
        if (SThread.sThread != null) {
             return;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it correct way of doing, any suggestions please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  - *"Is it correct way of doing,"* Maybe, most likely not. But It depends on the goal you want to achieve.

Comment: Too broad. Your refactoring proposal makes your code "less" good for a variety of reasons. In that sense: step back and read about SOLID OOP design rules for example. Whole books are written about proper design....please study them instead *assuming* that this or that change improves your code

Comment: okay, but now my task is to refactor the code.

I want to change code of "this.subscriptionThread".

Any suggestions please!

Comment: There is no 'alternative to use of this in static context in Java' because there is no such thing as 'use of this in static context in Java' in the first place.

Comment: “but now my task is to refactor the code”—who the hell assigns the task of refactoring without an actual goal (like making an actual improvement)?

Answer (score 3):

Static fields (unless they are final) are much frown upon so you use them sparingly.

Your class `mClass` had instance fields and methods, then you decided to factor out some operation on thread to an utility class.

Your utility class should be stateless and not rely on a static field, if you need a *global* variable the lightweight solution is to create a singleton, and host there your global variables.

Using singleton is frown upon too (but less then random static fields), the next step is a dependency injection framework like guice, weld , spring (you name it).

The bottom line is: try to keep data scoped, if you need a global field, think of it like a scoped field in an *Application Scope*.